# How to join ElasticSearch query with multi_match, boosting, wildcard and filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to acheve this goals:

1. Filter out results by bool query, like "status=1"
2. Filter out results by bool range query, like "discance: gte 10 AND lte 60"
3. Filter out results by match at least one int value from int array
4. Search words in many fields with calculating document score. Some fields needs wildcard, some boosting, like *importantfield*^2, somefield*, someotherfield^0.75
5. All above points join by AND operator. All terms in one point join by OR operator.

Now I wrote something like this, but wildcards not working. Searching "abc" don't finds "abcd" in "name" field.
How to solve this?

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "John Doe",
        "fields": [
          "*name*^1.75",
          "someObject.name",
          "tagsArray",
          "*description*",
          "ownerName"
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "status": 2
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "someIntsArray": 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "someIntsArray": 5
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "distanceA": {
                "lte": 100
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "distanceB": {
                "gte": 50,
                "lte": 100
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mappings:

```
{
  "documentId": {
    "type": "integer"
  },
  "ownerName": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  },
  "description": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "status": {
    "type": "byte"
  },
  "distanceA": {
    "type": "short"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  },
  "distanceB": {
    "type": "short"
  },
  "someObject": {
    "properties": {
      "someObject_id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  },
  "someIntsArray": {
    "type": "integer"
  },
  "tags": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please join your mappings.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot abut that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) if you would want to apply *wildcard* for multiple fields and at the same time apply various *boosting* values for individual fields:

Below is how your query would be:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "query_string":{  
                  "query":"abc*",
                  "fields":[  
                     "*name*^1.75",
                     "someObject.name",
                     "tagsArray",
                     "*description*",
                     "ownerName"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "status":"2"
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "bool":{  
                        "minimum_should_match":1,
                        "should":[  
                           {  
                              "term":{  
                                 "someIntsArray":1
                              }
                           },
                           {  
                              "term":{  
                                 "someIntsArray":5
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "range":{  
                        "distanceA":{  
                           "lte":100
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "range":{  
                        "distanceB":{  
                           "gte": 50,
                           "lte":100
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that for the field `someIntsArray`, I've made use of `"minimum_should_match":1` so that you won't end up with documents that'd have neither of those values.

**Updated Answer:**

Going by the updated comment, you can have the fields with wildcard search used by *query_string* and you can make use of *simple match query* with boosting as shown in below. Include both these queries (can even add more match queries depending on your requirement) in a combine `should` clause. That way you can control where wildcard query can be used and where not.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "query_string":{  
                  "query":"joh*",
                  "fields":[  
                     "name^2"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "description":{  
                     "query":"john",
                     "boost":15
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "status":"2"
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "bool":{  
                        "minimum_should_match":1,
                        "should":[  
                           {  
                              "term":{  
                                 "someIntsArray":1
                              }
                           },
                           {  
                              "term":{  
                                 "someIntsArray":5
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "range":{  
                        "distanceA":{  
                           "lte":100
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "range":{  
                        "distanceB":{  
                           "lte":100
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Wildcard works, but now I lost control on what fields wildcard will be used - now it's in all fields. Also filter "range" not filtering results. My test query https://pastebin.com/0iLh2R4H

Comment: @TomaszKane I've updated my answer and added new query in section `Updated Answer`. Could you please check. You can modify the answer and test it accordingly. Pay attention to the field names and values you use in search query and what you've provided in documents/mapping. Filter query is working fine at my end.